# How to combine multiple lists in R and organize according to common variable

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have multiple lists in R that each have unique species data according to an experimental setup. I already have the data parsed by experimental variable into separate lists and am looking to combine said data into one dataframe that shows me which variables have which sets of species (example below)

```
L1 <- c("ACRU","AHAA","ACHS","BLEH","HRFW","HWHW", "WBFW", "ZIMR")
L2 <- c("ACRU","AHAA","ACHS","BLEH")
L3 <- c("ACRU","HRFW","HWHW","ZIMR")
L4 <- c("ACRU", "AHAA", "HWHW", "WBFW")

df_list <- list(L1, L2, L3, L4)

df_list %>% reduce(full_join, by = "L1") #I thought this might organize according to the variable in question, but it does not.
```

What I am looking to create is:

| L1 | L2 | L3 | L4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACRU | ACRU | ACRU | ACRU |
| AHAA | AHAA | NA | AHAA |
| ACHS | ACHS | NA | NA |
| BLEH | BLEH | NA | NA |
| HRFW | NA | HRFW | NA |
| HWHW | NA | HWHW | HWHW |
| WBFW | NA | NA | WBFW |
| ZIMR | NA | ZIMR | NA |

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

L1 <- c("ACRU","AHAA","ACHS","BLEH","HRFW","HWHW", "WBFW", "ZIMR")
L2 <- c("ACRU","AHAA","ACHS","BLEH")
L3 <- c("ACRU","HRFW","HWHW","ZIMR")
L4 <- c("ACRU", "AHAA", "HWHW", "WBFW")

df <- tibble(
  L1,
  L2 = L1 %in% L2,
  L3 = L1 %in% L3,
  L4 = L1 %in% L4,
)

mutate(df, across(!L1, ~if_else(.x, L1, NA_character_)))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   L1    L2    L3    L4   
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 ACRU  ACRU  ACRU  ACRU 
#> 2 AHAA  AHAA  <NA>  AHAA 
#> 3 ACHS  ACHS  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 4 BLEH  BLEH  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 5 HRFW  <NA>  HRFW  <NA> 
#> 6 HWHW  <NA>  HWHW  HWHW 
#> 7 WBFW  <NA>  <NA>  WBFW 
#> 8 ZIMR  <NA>  ZIMR  <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`full_join` or any join, works only on dataframes. You only have vectors. You need to create a dataframe by column binding your four vectors without recycling. Here's one way to do it.

```
L1 <- c("ACRU","AHAA","ACHS","BLEH","HRFW","HWHW", "WBFW", "ZIMR")
L2 <- c("ACRU","AHAA","ACHS","BLEH")
L3 <- c("ACRU","HRFW","HWHW","ZIMR")
L4 <- c("ACRU", "AHAA", "HWHW", "WBFW")

df_list <- list(L1, L2, L3, L4)


max_length <- max(lengths(df_list))

lapply(df_list, function(x){
    length(x) <- max_length
    x
}) |>
    as.data.frame() |> 
    setNames(c('L1', "L2", "L3", "L4"))

    L1   L2   L3   L4
1 ACRU ACRU ACRU ACRU
2 AHAA AHAA HRFW AHAA
3 ACHS ACHS HWHW HWHW
4 BLEH BLEH ZIMR WBFW
5 HRFW <NA> <NA> <NA>
6 HWHW <NA> <NA> <NA>
7 WBFW <NA> <NA> <NA>
8 ZIMR <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Alright so this gets me about halfway there, but how can I organize columns L2, L3, and L4 according to the data in L1? Thanks!